# using libCurl with self signed certificate to download a file from local https host

Tags: c, curl, https, openssl, libcurl

I'm trying to download a file from https local host, using self signed certificate from embedded linux device.

1-When I do this based on BIO sockets and openssl library, I send HTTPS GET request and received plain  content HTTPS response addition content of the requested resource, when I request to WAMP server.

2- When repeat above action to the IIS server, authentication of HTTPS is done,I send request successfully and received HTTPS response successfully,but received data is weird non-string characters, which seems received data is un-decrypted .AS IIS received that as a success 200 request,which means My request successfully encrypt-send to server-decrypt on server and response send back to me,but maybe it was not successfully encrypt in server or decrypt in client .

3- using cross compiled V7.58 libCurl library,when I use

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
```

I'm able to successfully download file based on HTTPS protocol, but when I introduced self signed certificate pem file using below code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/addr/root.pem");
```

I received :

```
SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

and also root.pem file is ok as I tested that with openssl successfully.

4-testing number 3 using IIS server with libCurl also does not returned any data.
then could you please guide me how to run out of this weird damn situation?